# Retrieving specific value from a database php

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have a college project where users are able to register and login to a website. I have it set up so when registering a user enters their username, email, password, confirm password, address, and phonenumber. Once registered they are assigned a random string value, lets call it $randomString.

So my database is login_db and it contains the table user. The table headings are username, email, password, address, phonenumber, randomstring.

Its running fine a user can register, their details are added to the database and a user can login. When they log in they are redirected to admin.php. This page is blank at the moment.

Remember the $randomString people are assigned? I need to go into the database retrieve $randomString and display on admin.php.

This is what I've tried so far, I've only been able to display all users random strings but i need only the logged in users randomString. So im presuming the steps i need to go through are
1. Check IF user is logged in. maybe ----> if(isset($_SESSION['email']) ???? 
2. Check WHAT user is logged in. ????
3. Retrieve logged in users randomString.  ????
4. Display the random string. maybe ----> echo $result ???

I have absolutely zero idea how to do it so all help is appreciated.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'login_db');

if($connection) {
echo "we are connected";
} else {
die("Database connection failed");
}


?>


<div class="jumbotron">
<h1 class="text-center"><?php

$query = "SELECT randomString FROM users";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

print_r($row);

}

?></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: "Check WHAT user is logged in. ?? " ??

Comment: Well wouldnt I have to first check if a user is logged in then if a user is logged in find out which user is logged in?

Comment: Or could that be done in one step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain with your question :

> Check IF user is logged in

You need to set some value in session when user logs in your system,so that you can check that session value in each new request like you have said in your may be . i.e. `if(isset($_SESSION['email'])`

> > Check WHAT user is logged in. ????

If you want to find out which user had logged in then also you have to set all the user info
 (id,username/first or last name etc) in you session same as you had saved
user email in session.

> > Retrieve logged in users randomString

To retrieve logged in users randomString, you can query the database with the users info that you had kept in session when user logged in first time. i .e .

```
Select randromString from users_table where id='$_SESSION['id']'; //i had suppose you had kept id of logged in user in session here .
```

> Display the random string

To display the random string, yes now you simply echo the value of `$randomString` that you have retrieve from database using the query above.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for clearing that up for me :) much appreciated

Comment: @Lewk If you find this helpful then please accept the answer so that it can be helpful to others as well .

Comment: @Drudge your query is wrong. because you have not selected the id from the database, you have only selected the randomString hence this `where id=` might not be recognized

Comment: @OmariOmosa you can select any column from table buddy . where id= why not it will be recognized ??

Comment: @Drudge Ouw thanks i have tried it works. There is a time it gave me an error, lets say it was a different scenario

Comment: @OmariOmosa great :)

Answer (score 0):

First create the connection

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost = "localhost";
$database_localhost = "databasename";
$username_localhost = "root";
$password_localhost = "";
$localhost = mysql_pconnect($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

Secondly select what you want from the database for the logged in user

```
<?php
$colname_record = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
  $colname_record = $_SESSION['email'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_record = "SELECT userID, randomString, email FROM users WHERE email='$colname_record'";
$record = mysql_query($query_record, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($record);
$totalRows_record = mysql_num_rows($record);
?>
```

Thirdly get the variable of the logged in user and echo it

```
<?php
$randomstring = $row_record['randomString'];
?>
```

And display it

```
<?php
echo $randomstring;
?>
```

Comment: DO NOT SUGGEST TO USE mysql_* , because it is removed in PHP7.

Comment: Which one should i suggest? @Drudge

Comment: Check about PDO and mysqli .

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will try to keep updated

Comment: That's the spirit . :)

Comment: I tried this way also and it worked in the local host? If i took this on to a live server would it not work then? @Drudge

Comment: off course it should.

Comment: Going to work it out using your way anyway @Drudge. Thank you, your answers have been extremely helpful

Comment: @Lewk all you will need to do is change the connection